# Manage Timeout with Apache Camel

Tags: java, request, apache-camel, timeout

I have the following Route definition:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(String.format("direct:%s", this.connector))
    .id("Route1")
    .threads()
    .maxPoolSize(10)
    .keepAliveTime(3000)
    .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    .poolSize(1)
    .rejectedPolicy(ThreadPoolRejectedPolicy.Abort)
    .log("Calling WS")
    .maxQueueSize(1)
    .to("http://10.8.4.9:8080/service");
}
```

And the request snipet above:

```
InputStream exchange = (InputStream) template
            .requestBodyAndHeaders(url, AppUtil.parse(this.body, input), this.headers);
```

The endpoint is intentionally unavaliable. So, I expected my request wait for 3 seconds and throws some exception as response. Insted, the following behaviour happens:

```
    2018-08-24 16:55:55,048 DEBUG http-nio-8081-exec-2 httpclient.HttpMethodDirector:443 - Connection timed out: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
... more stack...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018-08-24 16:56:38,333  INFO http-nio-8081-exec-2 httpclient.HttpMethodDirector:445 - Retrying request
2018-08-24 16:56:38,417 DEBUG http-nio-8081-exec-2 httpclient.HttpConnection:692 - Open connection to 10.8.4.9:8080/service
```

Camel retries for 3 times and do not respect the timeout.

I've tried to use:

```
onException(ConnectException.class)
.maximumRedeliveries(0);
```

No success...

What I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.keepAliveTime(3000)` is not for HTTP endpoints, its an API for the JVM thread pool in Java itself. You can read about this option in the Java API for thread pools, and there is also a bit of javadoc on that method in Camel DSL.

If you need HTTP connection timeout etc, then you need to set specific option on the http endpoint.

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http4/src/main/docs/http4-component.adoc#using-client-timeout---so_timeout